# Why do I get "%lu" when I try to print a u64 variable with "%llu" instead of the number on a 32-bit embedded platform?

Tags: c, embedded, printf, overflow

I have a file from which I get timestamps for a streaming application. Timestamps are big numbers so I use `u64` data type in order to avoid overflows. Using `strtok`, I get correctly the string from a file giving me the number I need and then I use `atoll` or `strtoll` to convert the string to a `long long`.

When I print the number using the format specifier `"%llu"`, what is printed is `"%lu"`. I also compare the value I get from `atoll` or `strtoll` with the expected value and it is smaller, which I guess shows that an overflow has occurred.

Why does an overflow occur if the number fits in a `u64` variable? The number for example is 946688831000.

I should note that I have also used `long long` instead of `u64` and still nothing. Although it is working on Linux, on the embedded platform it does not.

Here is some sample code :

```
u64 timestamp;

char *inputTS = "946688831000";

timestamp = (u64) atoll(inputTS);

printf("Timestamp : %llu\n", timestamp);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  The likely problem is that the C implementation and library on your embedded system doesn't support 64-bit integers fully — specifically, the `printf()` function probably doesn't.  There's a lot of information missing.  In particular, which (version of which) embedded system are you using, and what's the compiler there?  We have to guess that `u64` is a typedef for a 64-bit unsigned integer type.  Since the code compiles, presumably `sizeof(u64) == 8` and `CHAR_BIT == 8`?  Does the library officially support 64-bit formatting?

Comment: Does your embedded platform support a 64 bit type? Either find the appropriate typedef for `u64` in your platform files or check `sizeof(u64)` on your embedded platform.

Comment: You may have to do some diagnostic printing.  For example: `u32 hob = timestamp >> 32; u32 lob = timestamp & 0xFFFFFFFF; printf("High-order bits: 0x%.8X; Low-order bits = 0x%,8X\n", hob, lob);` — working on the assumption that `u32` exists and is equivalent to `unsigned int`.  If that shows you zeros for the high order bits, then we have to wonder about 64-bit support on your machine; what does `u64` map to?  And what is its size, etc.

Comment: Work with one type at a time instead of `u64, long long, unsigned long long`: Try `printf("long long : %lld\n", atoll("946688831000");`  Then try  `printf("long long : %llu\n", atoull("946688831000");` if `atoull()` exist.

Comment: Yes the platform supports 64 bit type. sizeof(u64) = 8 and CHAR_BIT = 8 as well. You are right Jonathan the high order bits printed are 0. The compiler is an internal tool developped by a company and it is not available in public. It uses gcc and binutils but i do not really know every single detail on what is exactly used.

Comment: The full implementation of printf() can be very large.  Therefore some embedded tool chains provide the option to link with a smaller version of printf() that implements only a subset of the functionality.  See if your tool chain allows you to choose different versions of printf(), such as minimal, no float, or full.  If you can choose then make sure you've selected the right version.

Comment: @orestis : gcc *is* a compiler, so how can you say your compiler is an "internal tool".  However it is not the compiler in question here but the library implementation of `printf()`, `atoll()` etc.  - whose library are you using, and what version?  Modern versions of glibc support 64 bit format specifiers, but glibc has POSIX depenencies, so many baremetal or RTOS based embedded systems use alternatives such as newlib (current version of which supports `%llu`).

Comment: @Clifford you are right newlib/libgloss is used for the C standard libraries in my platform. I just got informed though that there is a problem concerning endianness on the platform so the problem is not on the function implementations. It is an issue not fixed yet on the platform.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple compilers for small embedded systems (including ones targeting ARM) have standard library without support for 64 bit formatting. It reduces stack usage and code size.

If you provide info about compiler and full command you use for linking it is possible that you are enabling this small library yourself (for example by using -fspecs=nano switch in arm-none-eabi-gcc from linaro)